# React speed up rendering of nested components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to implement a syntax highlighter using React. The syntax highligher component itself is Redux independent, but Redux is still relevant.

The highlighter takes 2 props

`structure` - It's a 2d array with the id's of tokens to be rendered, split to lines, example:

```
const structure = [
  [ // a line
    "ryMtafN9b",
    "r1WftTfEcZ",
    "rkfftaMV5W"
  ],
  [ // another line
    "B1sGYTG4cZ",
    "By3MYpzEq-"
  ],
  ...
]
```

`tokens` - A mapping between token id and token, example:

```
const tokens = {
  "ryMtafN9b": {
    "type": "LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET",
    "value": "[",
    "id": "ryMtafN9b"
  },
  "r1WftTfEcZ": {
    "type": "WHITESPACE",
    "value": "  ",
    "id": "r1WftTfEcZ"
  },
  "rkfftaMV5W": {
    "type": "LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET",
    "value": "{",
    "id": "rkfftaMV5W"
  },
  ...
}
```

The rendering then happens like this (removed all irrelevant stuff):

One token

```
class TokenElement extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    // return a <span> based on the token type, etc
  }
}
```

One row (line)

```
class TokenRow extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { tokens } = this.props
    return (<div>
      {tokens.map((token) => <TokenElement token={token} key={token.id} />)}
    </div>)
  }
}
```

The actual highlighter component

```
class JsonSyntaxHighlighter extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { tokens, structure } = this.props
    return (<pre>
      {
        structure.map((line) => (<TokenRow tokens={line.map((tokenId) => tokens[tokenId])} />))
      }
    </pre>)
  }
}
```

**The problem**
The reason I'm implementing a custom syntax highlighter, is because I need to add custom decorations on token level based on data coming in async. These updates coming in the form of extending each token in the `tokens` object, without mutations through a reducer (The whole highlighter component is rendered by a connected smart component). Even though all the components are `PureComponent`s the re-rendering of one single token takes a long time since:

1. `JsonSyntaxHighlighter` checks if needs to update - **YES** (since the `tokens` object changed in it's props)
2. `TokenRow` checks if needs to update - **YES** (since it's `tokens` array has changed, because it's a result of a `map`ping)
3. `TokenElement` checks if needs to update **MAYBE** (since now I can rely on `shouldComponentUpdate` properly).

Now when a lot's of these small updates arrive in a relatively small interval, the UI just blocks since a tons of re-renders are queued up.

**Question**
Can I structure my data or my components better, so that frequent changes in individual token's state can trigger renders fast, without checking the whole tree?

Comment: Maybe React v16 is something you want to look at because they have introduced priority. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCuYPiUIONs

Comment: Definitely! I installed the rc but they don't have async rendering in yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have proper code samples (it would be too much code to post here) but the way I ended up solving this is batching the plentiful store updates into chunks using `Observable`s (`rxjs`, `buffer` operator). This made the reducer code a bit more complex since state merges were not so natural, but now I have complete control over how frequently the store updates happen, and this implies control over how frequently `render`s happen.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook has a great article on exactly this topic.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)

Short answer is to use React's `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method generously to specify when whole the component tree should avoid updating. [Here are a few examples on how to do that.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#examples)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please read the whole question. The way `PureComponent`s `shouldComponentUpdate` works is exactly how I'd implement it by hand. The problem is the volume of incoming changes relatively the same time makes the re-rendering almost impossible.